# Must the number of people at a party who do not know an odd number of other people be even

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have a homework question in my discrete mathematics class as the title shows, I feel the answer is **no**, but googling this question seem's to contradict my answer. Let me explain:

So if they are asking about the number of people who do **not** know an **odd** number of people, they're asking about vertices with an *even* degree.

Theorem 1 in my book says:

> In any graph, the sum of the degrees of all vertices is equal to twice
>   the number of edges.

which means the result of the left hand side equation above (`DV = 2E`) **must** be even. The graph of the problem could in terms of the theorem above could be represented as:

$2nv_1$ + $(2m+1)v_2$ = 2E

where $v_1$ is the amount of even numbered vertices, and $v_2$ is the amount of odd numbered vertices

In the case above , the value of $v_1$ is arbitrary in the scope of this question as any number multiplied against an even number is still even. What *really* matters is the amount of odd people no? Consider the graph

[image]

this is valid, and an odd number of even degrees correct? I'm so confused partly because of [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100719115224AAphdjK) answer I found online, which states that it shoulds be **yes** , when the above graph proves it can be **no**.

Am I just thinking of this problem wrong? Thanks for any explanation

Comment: In your example, having even degree does not imply that there are an even number of strangers to you. (Indeed, it implies that there are an even number of strangers.) It will be simpler if you go with a different model and let the edge $xy$ denote that person $x$ does not know person $y$. This way you can just think about degrees and not complements of degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of even degree vertices could be anything but the number of odd degree vertices must be an even number.

Comment: So I'm not crazy right? The answer to the question would be **no** ?

Comment: I think, the answer should be "yes"

Comment: Consider the graph in which there is a edge between 2 people if they do not know each other

Comment: Now, the number of vertices with odd degree (i.e. the number of people who do not know odd number of ppl) must be even (acc. to the theorem)

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. Thanks!